# Getting backspace to work in a curses screen

Tags: c, curses, backspace

I work for the U.S. department of Labor. I am developing screens for states to help them predict how their Unemployment Insurance finds will perform for the next few years.

I am having a problem getting the backspace key to work in these screens, and I have a couple of complicating restrictions. The user will type a 
 numeric value in a field, and I have to show the user what is typed. This requires my to have echo(), I cannot use noecho().

The other issue is that the users are across all states in the country, and will have different terminals, so they will different values in their terminfo.

On November 2nd, I was able to get the following code to work, and then it stopped working the next day when I was required in the morning to update Google Chrome. That update apparently changed my terminfo.

Note that this code is a portion of 300+ lines of code in the module, I just included the code important to getting the backspace key to work:

```
WINDOW *win;

  main()
  {
    int key,i,x,y,newStrlen,accumFlag;
    char newString[8];

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    nonl();
    win=newwin(0,0,0,0);
    keypad(win, TRUE);

    echo();
    key=wgetch(win);

    if (key == 127) /* check for the backspace key */
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
           mvwprintw(win,y,x,"        ");
           wmove(win,y,x-1);
           newStrlen = strlen(newString);
           newString[newStrlen-1] = '\0';
           i -= 1;
           accumFlag -= 1;
           x = x - 1;
           wrefresh(win);
        }
    }
  }
```

I now get '^?' when I hit the backspace key. I have tried different if tests, such as

```
   if (key == KEY_BACKSPACE)
   if ((key == 127) || (key == 8) || (key == '\b'))
   if ((key == '^?') || (key == '^H') || (key == '\b'))
```

but nothing is working. I realize the two special conditions complicate this issue, but I hope someone can help me get this comparison to work.

Comment: Of course you can use `noecho()`, you just have to output the characters yourself manually. This is indeed how it is done in many cases, when a fine grained control over the screen is necessary (i.e. field size limits, _backspace handling_, etc. pp.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to create a text-entry field that users can edit. If this is correct, you should put the code to edit fields in a function.

As already noted, when you have `echo()` on, you will get echo for all kinds of stuff, *including* backspace, which *correctly* shows as `\?`.

***Turn echo off.***

Read every key. If it is a printable character (`isprint()`), simply add it to the currently-obtaining value for the field and update the field’s display, complete with `wrefresh()`.

I am also unsure of the way you are handling the field itself. You go to (y,x) and print a lot of spaces, then return to (y,x-1) — *outside* the area just filled with spaces — and then begin decrementing x — again to locations *outside* the area you cleared with spaces. This doesn’t look right.

Don’t worry too much about trying to optimize string output to the display. NCurses does that for you underneath. (Old time terminals, some of which your software may be interacting with, are very slow and NCurses was designed with that very much in mind: it has optimizations to deal with it.) So simply keep the field’s current state, and pad, crop, and print the string at y,x for every update.